# How do I add one phone number to more than one entity

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm working on a CoreData app that assigns volunteer phone numbers to different morning and afternoons of the week.  There are fourteen entities, one morning and one afternoon for each day of the week.

But now I want to add a fifteenth entity that I call "AllCall."  I want any entry to any one of the other fourteen entities to automatically be added to AllCall. That is where I am lost. I would greatly appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

I tried to just double my code for the new entity, but that didn't work. In fact, it prevented by original code from working.

Here is what I have:

import UIKit
import CoreData
import AVFoundation
import CloudKit

```
public var allSelected:Bool = false
public var phoneList = [String]()
public var phoneList2 = [String]()
public var switchStateArray = [String]()



class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var moc:NSManagedObjectContext!

var firstLaunch = true

var iCloudIsReady = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // SET UP ICLOUD

    print ("iCloudIsReady starts as \(iCloudIsReady)")

    self.navigationItem.title = "Waiting for iCloud...l"

    if self.iCloudIsReady == false {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Waiting for iCloud...l"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = false

    }

    else {

        self.iCloudIsReady = true
        self.navigationItem.title = SelectedEntity
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = false

    }



}

// BAR BUTTON OUTLET AND VARIABLES


@IBOutlet var selectAll: UIBarButtonItem!

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var SelectedEntity:String = ""
var List: Array<AnyObject> = []
var numberOfSections:Int = 1
var theSwitchTag:Int = 0
var theSwitchState:Bool = false
var alphaName:String = ""


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print ("Did numberOfRows")
    return List.count
}





override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {

    print (phoneList2)

    print ("View Appeared")

    phoneList2.removeAll()

    turnAllOff()

    allSelected = false


        self.navigationItem.title = SelectedEntity
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = false




    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


    moc = context



    let AppDel: AppDelegate? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)!

    let Context: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel!.managedObjectContext

     let Context2: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel!.managedObjectContext

    print ("Called persistentStoreDidChange")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TableViewController.persistentStoreDidChange), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,object:nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector:Selector("persistentStoreWillChange:"), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: moc.persistentStoreCoordinator)

    print ("Called persistentStoreWillChange")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector:"receiveICloudChanges:", name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: moc.persistentStoreCoordinator)


    self.loadData()

}



override func viewWillDisappear(animated:Bool) {

    print ("Deactivated these notifications")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object:nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: moc.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: moc.persistentStoreCoordinator)


    self.turnAllOff()


    self.moc.reset()



}


func persistentStoreDidChange() {

    print("Called persistenStoreDidChange")
 self.navigationItem.title =  (SelectedEntity)
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
    self.iCloudIsReady = true
    print ("iCloudIsReady is switched to \(iCloudIsReady)")

    self.loadData()
    self.tableView.reloadData()


}


func persistentStoreWillChange(notification:NSNotification) {

    self.navigationItem.title = "Changes in progress..."
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false


    moc.performBlock { () -> Void in

        if self.moc.hasChanges {

            let error:NSError? = nil
            try! self.moc.save()
            if error != nil {

                print ("Save error: \(error)")

            }

            else {

               self.moc.reset()

            }

        }



    }


}



func receiveICloudChanges (notification:NSNotification) {

    print ("Received iCloud changes")

    moc.performBlock { () -> Void in
        self.moc.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)

        self.loadData()


    }

}

// LOAD DATA FOR SELECTED DAY

func loadData() {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: SelectedEntity)

    let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [nameSort]


    List = try! moc.executeFetchRequest(request)


    for var i = 0;i<=(List.count-1);i+=1 {        


        let phoneBook: NSManagedObject = List[i] as! NSManagedObject

        let additionToList = (phoneBook.valueForKey("phonenumber") as! NSString as String)


        if phoneList.contains(additionToList) == false {

            print ("Added")

            phoneList.append(additionToList)
            phoneList2.removeAll()


        }

    }


    print ("The current dial list is \(phoneList2)")


}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    print ("I'm doing this")

    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

    let data: NSManagedObject = List[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject

    for var x = 0; x <= List.count; x+=1 {

        switchStateArray.append("OFF")

    }

    cell.Name?.text = data.valueForKey("name") as? String
    alphaName = String(cell.Name?.text)
    cell.PhoneNumber?.text = data.valueForKey("phonenumber") as? String
    cell.Group.text = data.valueForKey("group") as? String
    cell.FirstName.text = data.valueForKey("firstname") as? String
    cell.mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row
     theSwitchTag = cell.mySwitch.tag

    cell.mySwitch.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"

    let y:Int = indexPath.row

    print ("My indexPath.row is \(y)")

    if switchStateArray[y] == "ON"  {

        cell.mySwitch.setOn(true,animated:true)



        }


    else if switchStateArray[y] == "OFF"              {

        //user did turn off individual switch or did Delsect All

                cell.mySwitch.setOn(false,animated: true)


            }

    cell.mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: "switchChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    cell.mySwitch.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.mySwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;

    cell.Name.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.PhoneNumber.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.Group.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.FirstName.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


    return cell


    // Configure the cell...


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Change the color of all cells
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()


}


func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {


    let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource ("clicksound", ofType: "wav")
    let soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)
    self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL:soundURL)
    self.audioPlayer.play()



    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell


    let view = sender.superview!
    let parentCell = view.superview as! TableViewCell
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(parentCell)
    let intIndexPath = Int(indexPath!.row)



    if sender.on == true  {


        print ("You just turned on switch number \(sender.tag)")

       phoneList2.append(phoneList[indexPath!.row])


        print ("The value of indexPath is now \(intIndexPath)")

        switchStateArray[intIndexPath] = "ON"


        if phoneList2.count == phoneList.count {

            selectAll.title = "Deselect All"

        }


    }

    else if sender.on == false  {

        print ("You just turned off switch number \(sender.tag)")


        switchStateArray[intIndexPath] = "OFF"

        phoneList2 = phoneList2.filter({ $0 != phoneList[intIndexPath] })

        print ("I've removed \(phoneList[intIndexPath]) and the list is now \(phoneList2)")

        if phoneList2.count == 0 {

            selectAll.title = "Select All"

        }


    }

}

func turnAllOn() {


        switchStateArray.removeAll()
        for var x = 0; x <= List.count; x+=1 {

            switchStateArray.append("ON")

            phoneList2 = phoneList

        }

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}

func turnAllOff() {


    switchStateArray.removeAll()

    for var x = 0; x <= List.count; x+=1 {

        switchStateArray.append("OFF")

    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}

@IBAction func selectAllBtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    allSelected = !allSelected



    if allSelected == true {

        print ("allSelected is now \(allSelected)")
        print ("You pressed Select All")
        selectAll.title = "Deselect All"
        self.turnAllOn()

        print ("The dial list is now full: \(phoneList2)")


    }

    else {

        print ("allSelected is now \(allSelected)")
        selectAll.title = "Select All"
        print ("You pressed Deslect All")
        phoneList2.removeAll()
        self.turnAllOff()
        print ("The dial list is now empty: \(phoneList2)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()



    }


}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let AppDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let Context: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel.managedObjectContext

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        print("Before deletion, phoneList2 is \(phoneList2)")

        phoneList2 = phoneList2.filter({ $0 != phoneList[indexPath.row] })

        print ("I excluded \(phoneList[indexPath.row])")


        Context.deleteObject(List[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)


        List.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)


        print ("That name was deleted and the list is now \(phoneList2)")

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()


    }

    var error: NSError? = nil

    do {

        try Context.save()
    }

    catch let error1 as NSError {

        error = error1
        print (error)

    }

        }


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

    // MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goBack"  {

        self.turnAllOff()
        selectAll.title = "Select All"
        phoneList2.removeAll()

    }

    else if segue.identifier == "Compose" {

        print ("Compose pressed")

        self.turnAllOff()
        selectAll.title = "Select All"


    }


    if segue.identifier == "editRow" {


        print (segue.identifier)

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let selectedItem: NSManagedObject = List[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row] as! NSManagedObject

        let ViewCon = segue.destinationViewController as! AddViewController


        ViewCon.congName = selectedItem.valueForKey("name") as! String
        ViewCon.congNumber = selectedItem.valueForKey("phonenumber") as! String
        ViewCon.congGroup = selectedItem.valueForKey("group") as! String
        ViewCon.congFirst = selectedItem.valueForKey("firstname") as! String
        ViewCon.SelectedDay = SelectedEntity


        ViewCon.existingItem = selectedItem


    }


    else if segue.identifier == "addRow" {

        print ("I'm here")
        let ViewCon = segue.destinationViewController as! AddViewController
        ViewCon.SelectedDay = SelectedEntity

    }



}


}
```

Thank you for your help!

Eli

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making them all inherit from a parent object that has any properties you wanted to be global inside of it?

Comment: That sounds right, but I'm not sure how to do that in core data.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ParentObject: NSManagedObject {
}

class ChildObject: ParentObject {
}
```

The Child Object will inherit any attributes it parent has automatically. You will still need to set up a function of sorts that assigns it throughout all of the entities. Give the Parent Class all of the relationship info if it applies to all the children. Then when you access it from its inverse, you should be able to loop through each of it's children and set their global values. If you don't access them from a relationship, you should be able to just access them all from a fetch request to the ParentObject.